# Problem connecting asp.net core app to SQL server in a docker container

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker, asp.net-core, azure-data-studio

I have setup `asp.net core` applicaiton using `SQL Server Management Studio` on `Windows OS`, to be able to run same project on `Mac OS` I have setup `docker container` and running `SQL server` using `azure data studio` for management.

However I have tried various ways, it's not connecting and I think problem is with connection string..

**Connection String**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    //"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=BalDict; Integrated Security=false; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;",

    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=BalDict;user=sa;password=MySecurePass;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

  },
```

**I am getting following error**

```
SqlException: Cannot open database "BalDict" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

[image]

Comment: Just to certify. The second string seems the one you want, but it's commented. Did you notice this?

Comment: Is this database "BalDict" acessible on Azure DataStudio?

Comment: yes it's already connected in Azure DataStudio.

Comment: You mean due to the image? I mean, your Azure DataStudio is connecting at an "default" database (Based on what is said on "Recent" tab). If your user can connect to the server, but cannot access the database "BalDict", it will succeed in Azure DataStudio

Comment: Thanks.. Its working now. After checking again i realized while I re-download docker image and deleting old one, It deleted the database along with it. Just recreated the database and connection is working. Thanks for you time.